# Pure JS - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, html

> Note: I am aware this is a very frequently asked question but I am using pure Javascript and therefore I can't manage to fix it using the Node.js solutions on StackOverflow

I am trying to install the [Popup picker](https://picmojs.com/docs/usage/creating-pickers#popup-picker) from [Picmojs](https://picmojs.com/docs/getting-started/installation) but it was really tricky as it's not a usual library to import as a script tag.

For some reason, my code is working in Fiddle, but as soon as implemented on my web page, it throws the `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error.

Here's my [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwtyqdgr/) code:

```js
import { createPopup } from 'https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@latest/dist/index.js?module';

const triggerButton = document.getElementById('button');

// Create the picker
const picker = createPopup({

    className: "",
  hideOnClickOutside: true,
  hideOnEmojiSelect: true,
  hideOnEscape: true,
  showCloseButton: true,
  position: 'bottom-start', //https://floating-ui.com/docs/computeposition#placement
  //position: 'auto';
  
}, {
  // The element that triggers the popup
  triggerElement: triggerButton,

  // The element to position the picker relative to - often this is also the trigger element,
  referenceElement: triggerButton,

});

// The picker emits an event when an emoji is selected. Do with it as you will!
picker.addEventListener('emoji:select', event => {
  console.log('Emoji selected:', event.emoji);
});

triggerButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  picker.toggle()
});
```

```html
<input id="button" class="pickerContainer" type="button" value="Input Button">
```

However, when used on an HTML element of Bubble (a no-code editor), I get errors.

[image]

I also get the same result when the code is used in a script tag on Fiddle ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zwtyqdgr/1/))

```js
//import { createPopup } from 'https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@latest/dist/index.js?module';

const triggerButton = document.getElementById('button');

// Create the picker
const picker = createPopup({

    className: "",
  hideOnClickOutside: true,
  hideOnEmojiSelect: true,
  hideOnEscape: true,
  showCloseButton: true,
  position: 'bottom-start', //https://floating-ui.com/docs/computeposition#placement
  //position: 'auto';
  
}, {
  // The element that triggers the popup
  triggerElement: triggerButton,

  // The element to position the picker relative to - often this is also the trigger element,
  referenceElement: triggerButton,

});

// The picker emits an event when an emoji is selected. Do with it as you will!
picker.addEventListener('emoji:select', event => {
  console.log('Emoji selected:', event.emoji);
});

triggerButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  picker.toggle()
});
```

```html
<script type="module">
import { createPopup } from 'https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@latest/dist/index.js?module';
</script>

<input id="button" class="pickerContainer" type="button" value="Input Button">
```

Any hint on why this is not working? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: What is *pure Javascript*? There are about a dozen different versions, which one do you think is pure? I think you mean in the browser? But different browser still support different versions of the ECMA standards

Comment: Are you using babel or webapck or any other transpiler?

Comment: You need to read up about what a [JS module is and how to use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: right, so that ["import" is a node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@picmo/popup-picker). You can't just consume that in the frontend. You'll need to use a node module resolver, like webpack or babel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import local module inside of script from external html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70668902/import-local-module-inside-of-script-from-external-html)

Comment: Of course, [you've already been told this once already....](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73288847/542251)_

Comment: @Liam, Thanks! I am investigating your links. And yes I am basically trying to move forward from the solution on my other post you mentioned last.

Comment: You can't just keep asking the same question over and over and expect a different response.

Answer (score 0):

Main idea to have import in the same scope as your own code. Try something like that:

```
<html>
<input id="button" class="pickerContainer" type="button" value="Input Button">

<script type="module">
  import { createPopup } from 'https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@latest/dist/index.js?module';
  const triggerButton = document.getElementById('button');

  // Create the picker
  const picker = createPopup({

    className: "",
    hideOnClickOutside: true,
    hideOnEmojiSelect: true,
    hideOnEscape: true,
    showCloseButton: true,
    position: 'bottom-start', //https://floating-ui.com/docs/computeposition#placement
    //position: 'auto';
  
}, {
  // The element that triggers the popup
  triggerElement: triggerButton,

  // The element to position the picker relative to - often this is also the trigger element,
  referenceElement: triggerButton,

});

  // The picker emits an event when an emoji is selected. Do with it as you 
  will!
  picker.addEventListener('emoji:select', event => {
    console.log('Emoji selected:', event.emoji);
  });

  triggerButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
    picker.toggle()
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Of course, JS code inside  tag may be placed in a separate file

Comment: this isn't going to work. [`@picmo/popup-picker` is a node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@picmo/popup-picker)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Andrey Smolko, it almost answers it! The main goal is to integrate this code on a no-code app builder and use the variables provided by their editor as parameters from my createPopup function. Unfortunately, these variables will be inaccessible if I add my entire code inside the script tag. Also, I would like to be able to load the module first and then call the function later. Thanks again!

Comment: @Liam Well it worked pretty well on the Fiddle so far as long as not imported in the script tag...?

Comment: @Liam. Nope, it works as url https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@latest/dist/index.js?module contains **ES module** and you can consume it directly in your JS code, if you use module attr in script tag.

Comment: @vnihoul Did not you forget module attr for yout <script> tag?

Comment: I don't think so, it's on the `script` tag @AndreySmolko